# X/Y probability being within a range

Tags: probability

X and Y are two independent variables with a uniform distribution from 0 to 1.

What's the probability of 1 <= X/Y <=2?

Is it 1/4?

Comment: Hint: Draw a $1\times 1$ square, and shade in the area satisfying $1\le X/Y\le 2$.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I did and got 1/4. Is that correct?

Comment: @anonymous_99 Yes, it is. (by symmetry and the fact that the two non-congruent triangles have the same base and height).

Comment: @anonymous_99 Shall I add this as an answer?

Comment: Yes. This sort of method works in broad generality, and it's worth thinking about why it works. Roughly speaking, it's because the product of two uniform random variables on $[0,1]$ is a uniform random variable on the unit square: $[0,1]^2$. Probability is just special version of area/measure.

Answer (score 0):

Let the square $[0,1]^2$ have nodes $A=(0,0), B=(1,0), C=(1,1), D=(0,1)$ and $E=(1/2,1), F=(1,1/2)$.
The triangle $T_1 = \Delta ACE$ is the admissible region.
It is congruent (by mirroring along $\overline{AC}$) to $T_2 = \Delta AFC$ and it has base $\frac12$ and height $1$, as has $T_3 = \Delta AED$ and the congruent $T_4 = \Delta BCF$.   Since $T_1 \cong T_2$ and $T_3 \cong T_4$ and $\text{area}(T_1) =\text{area}(T_3)$, all triangles have the same area and cover the entire square disjointly, thus $\text{area}(T_i) = \frac14, i=1\ldots 4$.
Note that the base length and height would have sufficed as well, but you'd have to worry about the area of the square (wich here is $1$ conveniently).